# Is it possible to make this border around image?

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping to achieve a result like this and don't know where to start:

[image: Desired result]

```css
picture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: min-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="random image">
</picture>
```

Comment: Yeah, border could be a pseudo element and then transform the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:
[More info on 3D transforms](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-noobs-guide-to-3d-transforms-with-css-7370aafd9edf/)
[Pseudo elements](https://web.dev/learn/css/pseudo-elements/)

```css
picture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: min-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px) perspective(100px) rotateX(10deg);
}

picture::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  border: 4px solid orange;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" alt="random image">
</picture>
```